# MongoDB, using group by aggregate framework to get unique strings

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to use the aggregation framework to group a lot of strings together to indentify the unique ones. I must also keep some information about the rest of the fields. This would be analogous to me using the * operator in mysql with a group by statement.

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table
GROUP BY field1
```

I have tried using the aggregation framework, and it works fine just to get unique fields.

```
db.mycollection.aggregate({ 
    $group : { _id : "$field1"}
    })
```

What if I want the other fields that went with that. MySQL would only give me the first one that appeared in the group (which I'm fine with). Thats what I thought the $first operator did.

```
db.mycollection.aggregate({
  $group : { 
       _id : "$field1",
       another_field : {$first : "$field2"}
  }})
```

This way it groups by field1 but still gives me back the other fields attached to document. When I try this I get:

```
 exception: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)
```

Which I have a feeling is because it is returning the whole aggregation back as one document. Can I return it as another json array?

thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15307800/mongodb-single-document-size-limit-is-16mb

Answer (score 3):

You're doing the aggregation correctly, but as the error message indicates, the full [result](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/#result) of the `aggregate` call cannot be larger than 16 MB.

Work-arounds would be to either add a filter to reduce the size of the result or use map-reduce instead and output the result to another collection.

Comment: be careful you need to sort before taking the first element: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first

Answer (score 2):

If you unique values of the result does not exceed 2000 you could use group() function like

```
db.mycollection.group( {key : {field1 : 1, field2 : 1}}, reduce: function(curr, result){}, initial{} })
```

Last option would be map reduce:

```
db.mycollection.mapReduce( function() { emit( {field1 :1, field2: 1}, 1); }, function(key, values) { return 1;}, {out: {replace: "unique_field1_field2"}})
```

and your result would be in "unique_field1_field2" collection

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is use the `distinct` function:

```
db.mycollection.distinct('field1')
```

This functions accepts a second argument, a query, where you can filter the documents.

Comment: This is handy but does not solve the problem of returning all the other fields with the distinct document.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize this requirement. As the results are too big, you could use the $skip and $limit pipelines to partition the results. The trade-off here, is that you'll need run the aggregation many times and programmatically merge the results.