# Mongodb aggregate error

Tags: mongodb

this is the command and the error generate:

```
db.tweets.aggregate(
    {$project:{'entities.hashtags.text':1}},
    {$unwind:'$entities.hashtags'},
    {$group:{_id:'$entities.hashtags.text'}})

{
    "errmsg" : "exception: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)",
    "code" : 16389,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

i would want to do a follow query:

group by entities.hashtags.text and count the number of document that contains that hashtags for every hashtags taht exist.

this is a part of document:

...

entities: 
    {

```
   media: [

         ...

    ],

    urls: [],

    hashtags: [

        {

            text: "makeuploos",

            indices: [

                54,

                65

            ]

        },

        {

            text: "onbewerkt",

            indices: [

                66,

                76

            ]

        },

        {

            text: "hoer",

            indices: [

                77,

                82

            ]

        }

    ],
```

...

how can i do this??

Comment: Could you include a couple sample "entities" documents? In particular the array that $unwind is applied to is not clear to me.

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047572/mongodb-using-group-by-aggregate-framework-to-get-unique-strings/?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `$where` somewhere after unwinding and try match only relevant data. You just have to many different hashtags, and they do not fit in 16MB limit.

Answer (score 0):

From MongoDB v.2.6 you can use option **allowDiskUse**. For instance:

```
  db.tweets.aggregate(
    [
      {$project:{'entities.hashtags.text':1}},
      {$unwind:'$entities.hashtags'},
      {$group:{_id:'$entities.hashtags.text'}}
    ],
    {
      allowDiskUse: true
    }
  )
```

This will enable writing data to temporary files. 
You can find more info here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/#agg-memory-restrictions